# Viewing styled text in a JTextPane as HTML

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextpane

I've basically made a simple text editor with a JTextPane and some styling options (bold, italicize, underline, and center/right/left justify options), and I'm wondering if there is any easy way to view the HTML version?

What I'm eventually wanting to do is have an "export as HTML" type option that just has the plain text, but it's formatted with HTML tags instead of being styled.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want HTML, then you need to make sure the content type is `text/html` so the proper editor kit is used.

Then you use `textPane.getText()` to get the HTML.

Comment: That actually worked exactly like I was looking for. The problem was I kept forgetting to declare it HTML. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at any of the classes in javax.swing.text or javax.swing.text.html or javax.swing.text.html.parser?

Comment: I've really only looked into (or found) MinimalHTMLWriter, but what it does seems quite cumbersome to just drop into a program like I have now, so I was wanting to find out if there were any simpler alternatives, ideally.